# Changing Background for special Columns in an Oncoprint (Complexheatmap) in R

Tags: r, heatmap, bioconductor

This is my first question in this Forum but as it was helping me a lot before, I hope that you can help me with my Problem. 
I am working on a Genetic Analysis of Tumor samples and I have already created a wonderful Oncoprint with the ComplexHeatmap package from Bioconductor on R.

The Problem is that I have tested some samples with another test (for the specialists: with another targeted sequencing Panel) and I have added this also in the same Oncoprint which I have split into two. 
My Problem is, that I have not tested this for all samples, so I would like to Change the Background for samples, I have not tested to white.

[This would be the Image as I have it now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f0uH.jpg)
[image]

[This would be the Image where I have changed the Background for some samples. This is now made in Paint as an example on how I would like to have the blot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvQe.jpg)

I have tried to apply the Background aesthetics as a data.frame with all the colors for each position but this did not work. 
Maybe you can help me to find a solution?

Comment: Can you embed the images, as opposed to sharing links ? Makes it easier to go through question, and means the images will not be missing in the future.

Comment: As I am new to this Forum, I got an error, that I need at least 10 reputations to be allowed to post a Picture. I would prefer it embedded, too but unfortunately, I can't do it at the Moment! sorry